# SQLAlchemy OperationalError not fetched

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, sqlalchemy

Because we need to use different urls to access our DB for internal and external use, I implemented the following code. The problem is, that the raised *OperationalError* is not fetched by the *try/except* clause. Why is this error not fetched?

```
try:
    return create_engine('postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{dbname}'.format(
            dbname="db_name",
            user="username",
            host="internal_url.com",
            port=1234,
            password="PassWord"))
except exc.OperationalError:
    return create_engine('postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{dbname}'.format(
            dbname="db_name",
            user="username",
            host="external_url.com",
            port=1234,
            password="PassWord"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`create_engine` only create the instance but does not make the connection.
You need to connect to the db to verify if the connection is valid or not. Something like this

```
try:
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{dbname}'.format(
            dbname="db_name",
            user="username",
            host="internal_url.com",
            port=1234,
            password="PassWord"))
    engine.connect()
    return engine
except sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError:
    return create_engine('postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{dbname}'.format(
            dbname="db_name",
            user="username",
            host="external_url.com",
            port=1234,
            password="PassWord"))
```